# AWK script replace record in file1 with same record from file2

Tags: unix, awk

I'm trying to parse file2 for record 23 and use it to replace file1's record 23.

This is the command I'd like to run each time.

```
script.awk file1 file2
```

Here is an example of record 23 for either file. Same delimiters and number of digits in each value as well as having the same first field string.

```
currentmax: 1.7229 1.6888 1.1069 1.6238
```

This would then be the first section of a larger awk script. I would add more to this script to work only with the new values in file1 and output to file3 but that would be for later.

I'm not sure if a different file order in the command would make the script easier to write and then manipulate file1 until output to file3. Switching file1 and file2 may work.

```
script.awk file2 file1
```

Comment: May be it's just me but can you elaborate more on this? Like show us some content for file1 and file2 and you end result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to specify file2 first, because it has the data you want to capture.

awk has a couple of built-in variables that will help you. `FNR` is the record number of the current file being processed. `NR` is the record number of all lines seen so far.

To capture record 23 from file2 and replace file1's record 23:

```
awk '
  NR == FNR {
    # this block is processing the first file
    if (FNR == 23) line = $0
    next
  }
  FNR == 23 {$0 = line}
  {print}
' file2 file1 > file3
```

Comment: I had an off-topic question. How do with a file where we want to index a column which has same values but different other column values - eg `col1 col2 col3 \n A 33 45 \n B 30 00 \n A 43 99` where col1 is the column I need to index on and \n marks different records.

Comment: @Jaypal, I don't understand -- I don't see a question there. You will get better help with an actual question, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that in a separate command. It should be as easy as for example

```
{ sed -e '23,$d' file1; sed -n -e '23p' file2; sed -e '1,23d' file1; } > newfile
mv newfile file1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
l=23; a=c # l=line number a=c to change, a=i to insert or a=a to append
sed "$l"'s/.*/'"$l$a"' &/p;d' file2 | sed -i -f - file1
```